# Regular Expression for removing indentation

Tags: regex

I have a requirement to remove indentation from a numbered paragraph.   I currently do this with a couple of regular expressions and some code, but would like to accomplish it with one or more regular expressions.  The paragraph looks like this:

```
 1.  THE FIRST LINE OF THE PARAGRAPH
     ANOTHER LINE IN THE PARAGRAPH
         AN INDENTED LINE WITHIN THE PARAGRAPH
```

This needs to be transformed to retain the indentation within the paragraph, but remove the indentation of the entire paragraph as measured by the indentation of the first line.

```
THE FIRST LINE OF THE PARAGRAPH
ANOTHER LINE IN THE PARAGRAPH
    AN INDENTED LINE WITHIN THE PARAGRAPH
```

The following regex accomplishes the task by replacing matches with empty strings. (note that there are no tabs expected in this content, just spaces):

```
(\A *\d+\. *|^ {0,5})
```

But it requires that the indention length of **5** characters be set explicitly.  I would like a generic way of doing this that would work with any indentation length.  Any ideas for how one or more regular expressions (applied cumulatively) could accomplish this?

I am using the .NET regular expression engine with multiline mode turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other have indicated, regex (alone) probably aren't the correct tool for the job.

The major problem is that in order to strip the correct amount of spaces from all the further lines, you somehow need to store how wide was the first indentation. This is something that I'm not sure is doable with a regex engine alone.

If your desire for a regex based approach is just to have a quick one-liner than I think you can hack something like the following (I'm not familiar with .NET so I'll just provide you with a python solution):

```
re.sub(r"^([\d\. ]+)(.*)$", 
  lambda m: re.sub("^" + " "*len(m.group(1)), 
                   "", 
                   m.group(2), 
                   flags=re.MULTILINE), 
  paragraph, 
  flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
```

The idea is to have the outer regex isolate the indentation of the first line, while the inner regex takes care of removing the correct amount from subsequent lines.

In order for this to work the indentation must be made exclusively of spaces (i.e. no tabs) otherwise you'll have to do some assumptions on how many spaces a tab is made of.

That said you would probably better off implementing a custom parser to do the job. It would surely be cleaner and probably more efficient too.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you thought it would work, but your regex matches everything under the sun due to the right side of the |.

Try this:

```
^((?:\d+\.)? +)
```

Use something like http://www.regexr.com/ to test it out.

Comment: The expression to the right side of the | matches 0 to 9 spaces starting at the beginning of the line.  I think you did not see the space perhaps?   Your expression removes all of the space before each line, but does not preserve the indentation of the third line.   Thanks for your help though.

Comment: I just realized that my solution using the literal value of '9' was not what I had intended -- it should have been '4'.   I corrected that for clarity.

Comment: Aha, I see the trouble--when we encounter a match on a non-numbered line, we have no idea how many spaces to remove (which is based on an  earlier match).  I don't see how that is possible with Regular Expressions alone.

Comment: (The right side matches anything at all, because you are telling it to match "zero repetitions of a non-space character anywhere in the string".  Every string in the universe will match that.  Play around with it at regexr.com to see.)

Comment: ^ only means negation inside of a character class, like [^A] means match any char that is not A.   But outside of a character class it means match at the beginning of the line.   The literal actually should be 5 -- I have a space before the number -- I corrected question above.

I haven't been able to figure out a way to do it with one or more regex expressions.  So far my only solution is to store the length of the indent of the first line and use it in a generated regex expression for subsequent lines.

Comment: http://www.regexr.com/ doesn't support the \A character apparently.  That should match "beginning of file".  You can convert to ^ character.  And turn on multiine flag.

Comment: Sorry, you are of course correct regarding the ^ character--but my point remains regarding the rest of the right side: it matches all lines that begin with ""--which is to say, all lines without exception.

Comment: Point taken -- but on lines that don't start with spaces the match is a zero-length match and I am replacing with empty string -- so there is no effect.  It probably is a better idea to make the repetition {1,5} to make it clear that it is only interested in lines that begin with a space.